# Apex Test not able to execute Queueable and Future in same user context?

Tags: apex, unit-test, future

**Scenario ->** Queueable calls a Future method

In business process the Queueable calls another future method and future executes in same user context as its having some CRUD and FLS checks.

Now when the same runs in `Test` context, the `Queueable` runs in the running user context but the `Future` goes into System Context. (Admin user from org).

Here is the snippet.

Class:

```
public with sharing class TestFutureAndQueueable {

    public static void testFutureAndQueueable(){
        System.debug('Main called by -> '+UserInfo.getName());
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass());
    }

    public class QueueableClass implements Queueable {
        public void execute(QueueableContext param1) {
            System.debug('Queueable called by -> '+UserInfo.getName());
            callFuture();
        }
    }

    @Future
    private static void callFuture() {
        System.debug('Future called by -> '+UserInfo.getName());
    }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
@IsTest
private class TestFutureAndQueueableTest {
    @IsTest
    static void testBehavior() {
        System.runAs(getTestUser()){
            Test.startTest();
            System.debug('Test called by -> '+UserInfo.getName());
            TestFutureAndQueueable.testFutureAndQueueable();
            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }

    public static User getTestUser(){
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
        return new User(Alias='testuser', Email='test@user.com',
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='QueueTest', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', Username='QueueTest' + 'test@test.com');
    }
}
```

Logs gets printed when called from test is:

```
19:51:53.2 (934433688)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|Test called by -> QueueTest
19:51:53.2 (936242329)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|Main called by -> QueueTest
19:51:53.2 (985721175)|USER_DEBUG|[15]|DEBUG|Queueable called by -> QueueTest
19:51:54.11 (1012032385)|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Future called by -> Nagendra Singh
```

Why does future gets called in System context even after calling my method inside `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` ?

**UPDATE**

When we call future and then a Queueable it works fine and the user context is carried till Queueable.

```
public with sharing class TestFutureAndQueueable {

    public static void testFutureAndQueueable(){
        System.debug('Main called by -> '+UserInfo.getName());
        //System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass());
        callFuture();
    }

    public class QueueableClass1 implements Queueable {
        public void execute(QueueableContext param1) {
            System.debug('Queueable1 called by -> '+UserInfo.getName());
        }
    }

    @Future
    private static void callFuture() {
        System.debug('Future called by -> '+UserInfo.getName());
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass1());
    }

}
```

Test class :

```
@IsTest
private class TestFutureAndQueueableTest {
    @IsTest
    static void testBehavior() {
        System.runAs(getTestUser()){
            Test.startTest();
            System.debug('Test called by -> '+UserInfo.getName());
            TestFutureAndQueueable.testFutureAndQueueable();
            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }

    public static User getTestUser(){
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
        return new User(Alias='testuser', Email='test@user.com',
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='QueueTest', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', Username='QueueTest' + 'test@test.com');
    }
}
```

Console:

```
17:24:52.2 (510191209)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|Test called by -> QueueTest
17:24:52.2 (512422432)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|Main called by -> QueueTest
17:24:52.2 (524405041)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|Future called by -> QueueTest
17:24:52.2 (561178004)|USER_DEBUG|[18]|DEBUG|Queueable1 called by -> QueueTest
```

Comment: The _proximate_ cause is that `Test.stopTest()` only runs one layer of asynchrony, but I don't have an explanation for the observed change in user context, which probably can be explained only by reference to the gnarly technical details of the Apex test runner.

Comment: Interesting finding. Not the same thing, but it is worth noting that `System.runAs` only impacts async execution context when the `Test.stopTest` is within its scope (like you have done). Take a look at [this "idea"](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=0873A000000lJyq) for more. Fundamentally, context is dubiously and inaccurately handled for async in unit tests.

Comment: I agree with @DavidReed, it only runs with one layer of asynchrony.  So technically as of now there is no way to test the functionality without adding a `!Test.isRunningTest()` befire future call. And the call that separately again from test method. So that future and Queueable both runs in User Context.

Comment: Honestly, unit tests should not require verification that async processing executed correctly. Each individual component should be separately unit tested and dependencies mocked out. To do that requires a specific way of writing code for testing and mocking, of course.

Comment: I was testing this further and this statement `The proximate cause is that Test.stopTest() only runs one layer of asynchrony,` seems to be invalid. Updated my findings.